# How to sort and save data from 2 lists which doesn't have a pair

Tags: c++

So, today i've been trying to make a c++ program which will open 2 .txt files which contain numbers, read them, try to find if there is a number without a pair in the other file (123 in file A and 123 in file B).

So in 1 file i have numbers

```
123
122 
121 
120
```

and in other file i have numbers

```
101
102
103
123
```

When i run the program the output in the third file is

```
123
123
123
```

where i am hoping to see

```
122
121
120
101
102
103
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line1, line2, line3;
    ifstream iffile1;
    ifstream iffile2;
    ifstream iffile3;
    ofstream offile;

    offile.open ("lista3.txt");
    iffile3.open ("lista3.txt");
    iffile1.open ("lista1.txt");
    iffile2.open ("lista2.txt");
    if (iffile1.is_open() && iffile2.is_open() && iffile3.is_open())
    {

        while (getline(iffile1, line1) && !iffile1.eof())
        {
            while (getline(iffile2, line2) && !iffile2.eof())
            {
                if (line1 == line2)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    offile << line1 << endl;
                }
            }
        }

        iffile1.close();
        iffile2.close();
        iffile3.close();
    }
    offile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the order of the elements in the files have to be preserved?

Comment: Sounds like you need [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference)

Comment: @NathanOliver Only if the original order is irrelevant.

Comment: @cigien the order of the numbers does not need to be preseved, just have it write the numbers without a pair in the second file to the third file

Comment: You don't need an additional check for eof in these lines: `while (getline(iffile1, line1) && !iffile1.eof())`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the elements in each file into 2 `std::set`s:

```
std::set<int> n1;
std::set<int> n2;
int i;

while (iffile1 >> i)
  n1.insert(i);

while (iffile2 >> i)
  n2.insert(i);
```

and then output the symmetric difference between the sets to the output file:

```
std::set_symmetric_difference(n1.begin(), n1.end(),
                              n2.begin(), n2.end(),
                              std::ostream_iterator<int>(offile, "\n");
```

---

If the elements in each file are not guaranteed to be unique, you can read the contents of the file into `std::vector`s, and `std::sort` the vectors before computing the symmetric difference.

Comment: thank you so much, i really was doing it the hard way...

Comment: @LukaPancic No problem, I suggest taking a look at the [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) they'll help a lot. And consider accepting the answer when you can if it solves your problem.